# Is there a control that will fill image according to the width of the page

Tags: asp.net, webforms

Is there any control that I can use that will fill images according to the width of the page? In listview I have to give group item. I am looking for any data control that will automatically fill the images according to the screen width.

I am using asp.net webforms.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any control.

But you can use `css` or `jquery` for this. Creating `css` in `%` can be also a good idea.

Few links

1. http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/
2. http://www.minimit.com/articles/solutions-tutorials/fullscreen-backgrounds-with-centered-content